# In proguard, what is the keyword to preserve package/default access variables and methods?

Tags: java, ant, proguard

You can say:

```
-keepclassmembers class sun.** {
    public protected *;
}
```

But I am not excluding package/default access methods :(

```
void myMethod {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another `-keepclassmembers` like that:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.mycompany.MyClass {
  !public !protected !private *;
}
```

Comment: isnt there a specifier for "default" as well? Isnt it better than negating all the access specifiers?