# How to protect package-private and/or public classes from obfuscation by ProGuard?

Tags: android, proguard

I am looking at my current proguard configuration

`-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity`

and taking example from it, I created a marker interface `ProtectedAgainstProGuard` that I am going to use for all the classes I don't want obfuscated, in order to use such one-liner as the one mentioned above, rather than listing all the classes in the proguard file.

However, sometimes public classes will implement this interface, but sometimes package-private ones will implement it, so how do I state my rule?

a) `-keep class * implements com.myapp.ProtectedAgainstProGuard`

b) `-keep public class * implements com.myapp.ProtectedAgainstProGuard`

c) 

`-keep class * implements com.myapp.ProtectedAgainstProGuard
-keep public class * implements com.myapp.ProtectedAgainstProGuard`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In proguard, what is the keyword to preserve package/default access variables and methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183906/in-proguard-what-is-the-keyword-to-preserve-package-default-access-variables-an)

Comment: in lack of any other result, how do you get the opposite: obfuscate package-private classes that are used by other public (kept) classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: keep the interface, so that It doesn't get obfuscated

```
-keep interface com.myapp.ProtectedAgainstProGuard {*;}
```

Step 2: keep all the classes implementing this interface

```
-keep class * implements com.myapp.ProtectedAgainstProGuard { *; }
```